How to play chunked audio file without waiting for fetch to complete?
Is it possible to start playing audio using MediaSource (or something) without waiting for the complete data to be received ? For example, I have a very large audio file (several hours long) served using chunked transfer encoding, and I want to play it as soon as possible while the fetching process continues.
I've tried to fetch using standard code from MediaSource examples, e.g this. But audio player waits for whole file to be loaded.

fetch response body can be used as a readable stream - except in Safari (of course)

I know, but I can't figure out how to plug it into the audio sink. Supplying it directly as srcObject throws an error, noting that the source must be of type MediaSource

Instead of using fetch, is there any reason your not just doing audio.src = 'thebigfile.mp4' ??

I want to adapt this logic for a generative music synthesizer with an endless audio stream. This question is just the first step in a series of experiments

Ok, but just in case you didn't know endless audio sources are natively supported in most modern browsers.

There's no reason to do anything wild.  It's this simple:
<audio src="https://example.com/your-stream" preload="none"></audio>

The preload="none" is there for live streams, so that the browser isn't just downloading audio it isn't going to play.  You can take it out if your stream is not live.
Don't bother with MediaSource Extensions.  It does not gain you any functionality for this use case, and only hurts your client compatibility and codec/container choices.

Modifying the MediaSource examples code you gave, I came up with this


    const audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
    document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', audio);

    if (MediaSource.isTypeSupported('audio/mp4; codecs="opus"')) {
        const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', async function () {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(audio.src);

            const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('audio/mp4; codecs="opus"');

            const processStream = async (stream) => {
                const reader = stream.getReader();
                while (true) {
                    const {done, value} = await reader.read();
                    if (done) {
                        console.log("read finished");
                        return;
                    }
                    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(value);
                }
            }
            console.log('Fetching audio file...');
            const response = await fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/media-session/bear-opus.mp4');
            await processStream(response.body);
        });
    }



